# web3.js how to perform POST requests?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, web3js, contract-debugging, pyethereum

After reading the documentation [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Running-the-Testnet) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) I tried running the balance checker script from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/example/balance.html). I've modified the path to the source files and my code looks like (I've downloaded all javascript dependencies in the current working directory):

```
<!doctype>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bignumber.js/bignumber.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./web3.js/dist/web3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8000"));
    function watchBalance() {
        var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
        var originalBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase).toNumber();
        document.getElementById('coinbase').innerText = 'coinbase: ' + coinbase;
        document.getElementById('original').innerText = ' original balance: ' + originalBalance + '    watching...';
        web3.eth.filter('latest').watch(function() {
            var currentBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase).toNumber();
            document.getElementById("current").innerText = 'current: ' + currentBalance;
            document.getElementById("diff").innerText = 'diff:    ' + (currentBalance - originalBalance);
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>coinbase balance</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick="watchBalance();">watch balance</button>
    <div></div>
    <div id="coinbase"></div>
    <div id="original"></div>
    <div id="current"></div>
    <div id="diff"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I launch an instance of an http server using python's SimpleHTTPServer:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The node that I'm connecting to is running as a bootstrap node:

```
pyethapp -c eth.network_id=1337 -c jsonrpc.corsdomain='http://localhost:8000' --data-dir BootstrapDir -c node.privkey_hex=091bd6067cb4612df85d9c1ff85cc47f259ced4d4cd99816b14f35650f59c322 -b 'enode://288b97262895b1c7ec61cf314c2e2004407d0a5dc77566877aad1f2a36659c8b698f4b56fd06c4a0c0bf007b4cfb3e7122d907da3b005fa90e724441902eb19e@127.0.0.1:29873' -c eth.genesis=CustomGenesis.json -m 100 run
```

When I debug the script in Chrome, I get the following errors:

```
    httpprovider.js:77 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 501 
(Unsupported method ('POST'))
HttpProvider.send @ 
httpprovider.js:77RequestManager.send @ 
requestmanager.js:58get @ 
property.js:107watchBalance @ 
balance.html:14onclick @ 
balance.html:28

    errors.js:35 Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "
<head>\n<title>Error response</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Error response</h1>\n<p>Error code 501.\n<p>Message: Unsupported method ('POST').\n<p>Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation.\n</body>\n"
InvalidResponse @ 
errors.js:35HttpProvider.send @ 
httpprovider.js:87RequestManager.send @ 
requestmanager.js:58get @ 
property.js:107watchBalance @ 
balance.html:14onclick @ 
balance.html:28
```

Is there a workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue; it was related to the **SimpleHTTPServer**. I'm using apache now. I've set apache to listen on a non-default port by editing **port.conf**:

```
# find / -name *conf | grep apache
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dnssd.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/autoindex.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/cgid.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime_magic.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_fs.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_ftp.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/actions.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy_balancer.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/cache_disk.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/info.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/setenvif.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ldap.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/negotiation.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/reqtimeout.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/charset.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/apache2-doc.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/setenvif.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/negotiation.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/php5-cgi.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/javascript-common.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/charset.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/localized-error-pages.conf
/etc/apache2/conf-available/apache2-doc.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Set a non-standard port for apache:

```
vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf
Listen 8000
```

Restart apache (on debian):

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And copy the html file along with the javascript dependencies to the web root:

```
sudo cp -r ethreum_js/ /var/www/html
```

You can also create a [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) for testing the **web3.js**'s functionality.